# Chromium will not launch

Tags: linux, permissions, chrome

I can launch chromium by right clicking and selecting “open a new window with a temporary profile”. However I can not get it to work with my normal user profile. I get the following errors:

```
kurt@pop-os:~$ chromium-browser 
[18769:18786:0620/131321.807483:ERROR:cache_util.cc(141)] Unable to move cache folder /home/kurt/.config/chromium/ShaderCache/GPUCache to /home/kurt/.config/chromium/ShaderCache/old_GPUCache_000 
[18769:18786:0620/131321.807515:ERROR:disk_cache.cc(178)] Unable to create cache [18769:18786:0620/131321.807521:ERROR:shader_disk_cache.cc(623)] Shader Cache Creation failed: -2 
[18769:18769:0620/131321.854367:ERROR:process_singleton_posix.cc(433)] readlink failed: Permission denied (13) 
[18769:18769:0620/131321.854396:ERROR:process_singleton_posix.cc(257)] readlink(/home/kurt/.config/chromium/SingletonLock) failed: Permission denied (13)
[18769:18769:0620/131321.854416:ERROR:process_singleton_posix.cc(257)] readlink(/home/kurt/.config/chromium/SingletonLock) failed: Permission denied (13)
[18769:18769:0620/131321.854423:ERROR:process_singleton_posix.cc(281)] Failed to create /home/kurt/.config/chromium/SingletonLock: Permission denied (13)
[18769:18769:0620/131321.854433:ERROR:process_singleton_posix.cc(433)] readlink failed: Permission denied (13) 
[18769:18769:0620/131321.854440:ERROR:process_singleton_posix.cc(257)] readlink(/home/kurt/.config/chromium/SingletonLock) failed: Permission denied (13)
[18769:18769:0620/131321.854467:ERROR:chrome_browser_main.cc(1408)] 
Failed to create a ProcessSingleton for your profile directory. This means that running multiple instances would start multiple browser processes rather than opening a new window in the existing process. Aborting now to avoid profile corruption. 
[18769:18786:0620/131321.870458:ERROR:browser_process_sub_thread.cc(221)] 
Waited 13 ms for network service
```

Running `ls -la /home/kurt/.config/chromium/` outputs the following:

```
kurt@pop-os:~$ ls -la /home/kurt/.config/chromium/  
ls: cannot open directory '/home/kurt/.config/chromium/': Permission denied
```

Any ideas how to get it to work?

I am using Pop OS Gnu/Linux.

Comment: Can you provide the output from the command, `ls -la /home/kurt/.config/chromium/`; it looks to be a permissions issue with this directory.

Comment: Did you previously run the browser as another user (root?). If so, some of the files may be owned by that other user.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was solved by deleting the configuration directory

```
/home/kurt/.config/chromium/
```

Chromium was able to run and generate new configuration files, free of permission issues.

Thank you for the edits and comments

Comment: Did the new config get created under ~/snap/? I resolved a similar problem with `[18769:18769:0620/131321.854396:ERROR:process_singleton_posix.cc(257)] readlink(/home/kurt/.config/chromium/SingletonLock) failed: Permission denied (13)
` by moving my chromium data dir from `.config` to a directory without a '.' in the path.
I bounced my user dir between ~/foo (worked) and ~/.foo (failed with that error).